# How do you start VScode with Powershell without it being tied to the console window?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using a powershell script to start a few programs in sequence, but the powershell window stays open after starting the programs (I wish it wouldn't). No problem though, I can just close the window - but if I do, it closes VScode (one of the programs I started).

Can I either get powershell to start the other programs and then go away OR at least start the programs in a way that they're not tied to the console?

I'm using very simple code:

```
Start-Process -Filepath "Path to vscode"
Start-Process -Filepath "Path to firefox"
Start-Process -Filepath "Path to chrome"
```

etc.

Comment: VS Code is [special in this regard](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66750).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `; exit` after your last cmdlet as shown below. The processes will start, the powershell window will close, but the processes will stay open.

```
Start-Process -Filepath "Path to vscode"
Start-Process -Filepath "Path to firefox"
Start-Process -Filepath "Path to chrome"; exit
```

Comment: I was about to say it doesn't work, but I put the exit on the same line like you did and it did suddenly. I don't know why that would make a difference, but it seems to have worked.

Comment: I forgot, I did make one other change. The VS code line wasn't the last in my actual file, but I made it the last one. Perhaps that was the difference.